# Split Columns in pandas with str.split and keep values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am stuck with a problem here:

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the following:

```
ID Name    Value
0  Peter   21,2
1  Frank   24
2  Tom     23,21/23,60 
3  Ismael  21,2/ 21,54
4  Joe     23,1

and so on...
```

What I am trying to is to split the "Value" column by the slash forward (/) but keep all the values, which do not have this kind of pattern.

Like here:

```
ID Name    Value
0  Peter   21,2
1  Frank   24
2  Tom     23,21
3  Ismael  21,2
4  Joe     23,1
```

How can I achieve this? I tried the str.split method but it's not giving me the solution I want. Instead, it returns NaN as can be seen in the following.

```
My Code: df['Value']=df['value'].str.split('/', expand=True)[0]

Returns:

ID Name    Value
0  Peter   NaN
1  Frank   NaN
2  Tom     23,21
3  Ismael  21,2
4  Joe     Nan
```

All I need is the very first Value before the '/' is coming.

Appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `expand=True` for return lists and add `str[0]` for select first value:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.split('/').str[0]
print (df)
   ID    Name  Value
0   0   Peter   21,2
1   1   Frank     24
2   2     Tom  23,21
3   3  Ismael   21,2
4   4     Joe   23,1
```

If performance is important use list comprehension:

```
df['Value'] = [x.split('/')[0] for x in df['Value']]
```

Comment: Both solution are not working for some reasons.. it still gives me the same output as the one I already achieved with mine. Second solution gives me the error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Lars - How working `df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(str).str.split('/').str[0]` ?

Comment: however.. now I am dealing with endless nan´s.. how can I convert it back to floats so I can run some stats on those values?

Comment: @Lars - Use `df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].astype(str).str.split('/').str[0].replace(',','.', regex=True))`

Comment: Now I get a "ValueError: Unable to parse string "nan" at position 4"

Comment: @Lars - Then use `df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].astype(str).str.split('/').str[0].replace(',','.', regex=True), errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

#### `pandas.Series.str.replace` with regex

```
df.assign(Value=df.Value.str.replace('/.*', ''))

   ID    Name  Value
0   0   Peter   21,2
1   1   Frank     24
2   2     Tom  23,21
3   3  Ismael   21,2
4   4     Joe   23,1
```

---

Optionally, you can assign results directly back to dataframe

```
df['Value'] = df.Value.str.replace('/.*', '')
```